# Dataframe cell to be locked and used for a running balance calculation conditional of result on another cell on same row

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Say I have the following dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame()

df['A'] = ('1/05/2019','2/05/2019','3/05/2019','4/05/2019','5/05/2019','6/05/2019','7/05/2019','8/05/2019','9/05/2019','10/05/2019','11/05/2019','12/05/2019','13/05/2019','14/05/2019','15/05/2019','16/05/2019','17/05/2019','18/05/2019','19/05/2019','20/05/2019')

df['B'] = ('SIT','SCLOSE', 'SHODL', 'SHODL', 'SHODL', 'SHODL', 'SHODL', 'SELL','SIT','SIT','BCLOSE', 'BHODL', 'BHODL', 'BHODL', 'BHODL', 'BHODL', 'BHODL','BUY','SIT','SIT')

df['C'] = (0.00,1.00,10.00, 5.00,6.00,-6.00, 6.00, 0.00,0.00,0.00,-8.00,33.00,-15.00,6.00,-1.00,5.00,10.00,0.00,0.00,0.00)

df.loc[19, 'D'] = 100.0000
```

As can be seen I am starting column D with 100 at the last row.

I am trying to code a calculation for column D so starting from the bottom row (row 19) when a BUY or SELL is shown on column B then the number on column D is locked (eg the 100) and used for a calculation based on col C for each SHODL or BHODL until the row after a BCLOSE or an SCLOSE is shown.

The locked number is used to calculate a running balance based on the percentages that are in column C. As you can see on row 16 column C has '10' representing 10%. As 10% of 100 = 10 the new runnning balance is 110.

Row 15 column C has 5% as such 5 is added to the running balance to result in 115.

The next row 14 column C has a -1% change as such 1% of 100 is = 1 and therefore the new running balance is 114 and so on.

The following are the results that should be returned in col D of the dataframe once the right code is run

```
df['D'] = ('158.60','158.60', '157.30', '144.30', '137.80', '130.00', '137.80', '130.00','130.00','130.00','130.00', '138.00', '105.00', '120.00', '114.00', '115.00', '110.00','100.00','100.00','100.00')
```

This continues until after a SCLOSE or a BCLOSE is shown as a BCLOSE or SCLOSE row is the final row where the running balance is calculated.

As you can see this process is restarted when either a new BUY or SELL is shown.

Comment: let me know if the above doesn't make sense or if you have any questions

Comment: The chronology of calculation you mentioned goes from row 19 to row 0. Is that right or should the DataFrame be reversed?

Comment: Yeah mate thats how it is irl so may need to reverse df to perform calculation then reverse back to the state so it looks like col D

Comment: Also, is it necessary to use pandas? seems like a easy solution using iteration when using simple lists or dicts.

Comment: Hi nishant I started a bounty so hope you can take another look

Comment: I only see "SIT", not "SELL"?

Comment: Hi cs95, there is a 'SELL' on row 7 of my example dataframe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Next starting value depends on the last value of previous group, so I think it can't be vectorized. It requires some kind of iterative process. I came up with solution doing iteratively on groups of groupby. Reverse `df` and assign to `df1`. Working on each group of `df1` and assign the final list of groups to the original `df`

```
df1 = df[::-1]
s = df1.B.isin(['BCLOSE','SCLOSE']).shift(fill_value=False).cumsum()
grps = df1.groupby(s)
init_val= 100
l = []
for _, grp in grps:
    s = grp.C * 0.01 * init_val
    s.iloc[0] = init_val
    s = s.cumsum()
    init_val = s.iloc[-1]
    l.append(s)

df['D'] = pd.concat(l)

Out[50]:
             A       B     C      D
0    1/05/2019     SIT   0.0  158.6
1    2/05/2019  SCLOSE   1.0  158.6
2    3/05/2019   SHODL  10.0  157.3
3    4/05/2019   SHODL   5.0  144.3
4    5/05/2019   SHODL   6.0  137.8
5    6/05/2019   SHODL  -6.0  130.0
6    7/05/2019   SHODL   6.0  137.8
7    8/05/2019    SELL   0.0  130.0
8    9/05/2019     SIT   0.0  130.0
9   10/05/2019     SIT   0.0  130.0
10  11/05/2019  BCLOSE  -8.0  130.0
11  12/05/2019   BHODL  33.0  138.0
12  13/05/2019   BHODL -15.0  105.0
13  14/05/2019   BHODL   6.0  120.0
14  15/05/2019   BHODL  -1.0  114.0
15  16/05/2019   BHODL   5.0  115.0
16  17/05/2019   BHODL  10.0  110.0
17  18/05/2019     BUY   0.0  100.0
18  19/05/2019     SIT   0.0  100.0
19  20/05/2019     SIT   0.0  100.0
```

Comment: Thanks Andy your answer works straight out of the box.  I prefer the format of Arn's answer below however it had an error when the top row was a BCLOSE or an SCLOSE, your answer didn't have this problem

Comment: Hi Andy, I have a follow up question to this one. I will give you 50 bounty points upon successful answer. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60751491/dataframe-cell-to-be-locked-and-used-for-a-running-balance-calculation-follow-u

Comment: Let me know if you have any questions

Comment: @ds882: I posted an answer to the new question

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a more optimized and pythonic way to solve this. But a solution with iteration:

```
df['D'] = pd.to_numeric(df['D'])
df['C'] = pd.to_numeric(df['C'])
D_val = None
for i in range(len(df)-1, 0, -1):
    if df.loc[i, 'B'] == 'BUY':
        D_val = df.loc[i, 'D']
        continue
    if D_val is None:
        continue
    df.loc[i, 'D'] = df.loc[i+1, 'D'] + (D_val * df.loc[i, 'C']/100)
```

Everytime you encounter a `BUY` in `column D`, you update the `D_val`. We can also have a condition to stop as mentioned by OP such as `SCLOSE` or `BCLOSE`.

Comment: Thanks mate, but I am a little confused with your code or am not sure if it was I require. Bascially I provided col D as only an example of what the result I require should end up looking like. How do Iget to col D based on only col B and C

Comment: Hi @nishant I have edited my question.  Maybe it now makes more sense

Comment: The initial value from where we start calculating D must be stored somewhere. If there is no column `D`, we can start from initial variable and then progressively populate `D`. The above code would still work.

Comment: Can you once try the above piece of code and let me know the issues/differences in result from the expected result.

Comment: Hi nishant if I simply add your code under my code above I just get an error message. Is there something else I need to do?

Answer (score 0):

This piece below should help you out. It produces the expected output and it's relatively fast because it avoids the direct iteration on the dataframe's rows.

```
endpoints = [df.first_valid_index(), df.last_valid_index()]
# occurrences of 'BCLOSE' or 'SCLOSE'
breakpoints = df.index[(df.B =='BCLOSE') | (df.B == 'SCLOSE')][::-1]
# remove the endpoints of the dataframe that do not break the structure
breakpoints = breakpoints.drop(endpoints, errors='ignore')

PERCENTAGE_CONST = 100
top = 100  # you can specify any initial value here

for i in range(len(breakpoints) + 1):

    prv = breakpoints[i - 1] - 1 if i else -1  # previous or first breakpoint
    try:
        nex = breakpoints[i] - 1  # next breakpoint
    except IndexError:
        nex = None  # last breakpoint

    # cumulative sum of appended to 'D' column
    res = top + (df['C'][prv: nex: -1] * top / PERCENTAGE_CONST).cumsum()[::-1]
    df.loc[res.index, 'D'] = res

    # saving the value that will be the basis for percentage calculations
    # for the next breakpoint
    top = res.iloc[0]
```

Comment: Hi Arn. This looks good and I think we are almost there, however there is 1 issue. Column C figures are meant to be percentages as I describe in my outline not the actual amount of gain or loss. If you change the top/begin variable from 100 to 1000 the result of row 0 should be '1586.0' (ie 10x current value) however it is currently 1052.66 with your code. Cheers mate

Comment: Hi, I've just edited my answer. It works with other values now.

Comment: Hi Arn sorry for the late reply just other things on.  Yes your answer is great, however I have found 1 more issue. If you delete the top row of my example dataframe so the new top row has col B as SCLOSE then run with your code I get the following error.  'raise IndexError("single positional indexer is out-of-bounds")
IndexError: single positional indexer is out-of-bounds'.  It is in regards to the following line 'top = res.iloc[0]'.  It looks as though your code gets and error if the top row is and SCLOSE or BCLOSE

Comment: Its just in real life when I run your code I will end up with a BCLOSE's and SCLOSE's with a project and cannot have and error. Other than that I really like how readable you have prepared the code

Comment: Hi Arn, I have a follow up question to this one. I will give you 50 bounty points upon successful answer. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60751491/dataframe-cell-to-be-locked-and-used-for-a-running-balance-calculation-follow-u

Comment: Let me know if you have any questions